# No BIOS boot options

Tags: boot, ssd, bios, unix

Today out of the blue, I encountered the following problem: whenever I turn on the pc, it goes directly to the BIOS instead of opening GRUB. The problem is that it doesn't show any drive in the boot options. I've looked everywhere I think and this is what I've done (in vain) to try to resolve the issue:

1. Originally I thought that the problem was the SSD, so I tried booting from an external Ubuntu USB, but it didn't shiw it anywhere.
2. I found that all the drives were listed in the "SATA Configuration" section, but they weren't recognized.
3. I disabled Secure Boot, and enabled CSM, this lead to the BIOS showing the drives as valid boot options, but would shutdown if I tried booting from them, and on startup it displays the following message:

> Reboot and Selecy proper boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key

I have no clue what to try next. The SSD I'm trying to boot from has a bootable debian image.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like the drive has failed. Some failure modes of SSDs have the underlying flash device failing while the controller still works, the result is a drive that appears to the BIOS but has no storage at all.

Comment: @Mokubai That wouldn't explain why the USB stick wasn't recognized either.